# Simple HTML page getting JS errors- "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" and "ReferenceError: calculateAdvantage is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS, and I've looked online, but I'm still not sure why I'm getting these errors. I have an index.html and a CSS sheet. The JS seems to be problematic but I can't figure out why.

The user is supposed to input a few values, click the button, and then the function should trigger and make a change to the "result" div element.

Index.HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Out of Shield Options</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Out of Shield</h1>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h2>Calculator</h2>
    <div id="inputInfo">
        <div class="inputLabel">
            <label>Hit Frame:</label><input type="text" class ="textField" id="hitFrame" class="inputs" value="0"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="inputLabel">
            <label>IASA Frame:</label><input type="text" class ="textField" id="iasaFrame" class="inputs" value="0"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="inputLabel">
            <label>Damage:</label><input type="text" class ="textField" id="damage" class="inputs" value="0"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="submit"><input id="calculateButton"type="button" value="Calculate!" onclick="calculateAdvantage()"></div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        calculateAdvantage(){
            var hitFrame = document.getElementById("hitFrame");
            var IASA = document.getElementById("iasaFrame");
            var damage = document.getElementById("damage");


            var shieldStun = (damage / 1.75) + 2;

            var result = IASA - hitFrame - shieldStun; 
            document.getElementById("calculateButton").innerHTML = result;
        }
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare `calculateAdvantage` as a function:

```
function calculateAdvantage() {
    // Your code goes there
}
```